# User's threads in Thin, Sinatra application on Heroku

Tags: ruby, multithreading, heroku, sinatra

I have a set of time-costly operations which are specific for every single user of my app, it's all encapsulated in a method (e.g `write_collections` method). In this method program communicates with Facebook and MongoDB. I want to run this method in a thread for every user.

This thread is called in `get '/'` Sinatra route but result of thread (a state in database) is needed only on `get '/calculate'`. My idea is to run the thread on `get '/'` and to join it on `get '/calculate'` to ensure that all the user's data has written properly in database before calculating results for the user starts.

To illustrate:

---

## Approach I

```
get "/" do    
  @user = @graph.get_object("me")

  data_thread = Thread.new do
    write_collections(@user)
  end

  session[:data_thread] = data_thread.object_id

  erb :index
end

get "/calculate" do
  begin
  # Is this safe enough?
  if ObjectSpace._id2ref(session[:data_thread]).alive?
      data_thread = ObjectSpace._id2ref(session[:data_thread])
      data_thread.join
  end
  rescue RangeError => range_err
    # session[:data_thread] is not id value
    # direct access to /calculate without session
  rescue TypeError => type_err
    # session[:data_thread] is nil
  end

  # do calculations based on state in database
  # and show results to user

  "<p>Under construction</p>"
end
```

To find the proper thread on which specific user should waiting to join I currently use `ObjectSpace._id2ref(session[:data_thread])`.

- Is it safe enough?

### *Detailed*:

From the official Ruby docs for `Object#object_id`:

> object_id → fixnum:
>   Returns an integer identifier for obj. The same number will be returned on all calls to id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id.

and for `ObjectSpace`:

> The ObjectSpace module contains a number of routines that interact with the garbage collection facility and allow you to traverse all living objects with an iterator.

- Is 'active object' from the first quote same as 'living object' from the second?

Let's assume following situation:

1. User **A** access `'/'` [now **A** thread is started with `object_id` **a**]
2. Thread **A** is finished [it is not active anymore and it's `object_id` is released]
3. User **B** access `'/'` [now **B** thread is started with the same `object_id` **a** (* *is it possible?*)]
4. User **A** access `'/calculate'` [`session[:data_thread]` is **a** so `ObjectSpace._id2ref(session[:data_thread])` is actually **B** thread.]
5. Inconsistent state - user **A** is waiting for thread **B**.

   - Is this scenario possible within Sinatra, Thin, Heroku?

---

## Approach II

```
configure do
  # map user_id to corresponding user's thread
  data_threads_hash = {}
  set :data_threads_hash, data_threads_hash
end

get "/" do    
  @user = @graph.get_object("me")

  data_thread = Thread.new do
    write_collections(@user)
  end

  session[:user_id] = @user['id']
  settings.data_threads_hash[session[:user_id]] = data_thread

  erb :index
end

get "/calculate" do

  if settings.data_threads_hash[session[:user_id]].alive?
    data_thread = settings.data_threads_hash[session[:user_id]]
    data_thread.join
    settings.data_threads_hash.delete session[:user_id]
  end

  # do calculations based on state in database
  # and show results to user

  "<p>Under construction</p>"

end
```

### *Detailed*:

I tried this after reading [Sinatra: README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Further%20Reading).
Under **Configuration**:

> Run once, at startup, in any environment
>   ...
>   You can access those options via settings
>   ...

And under **Scopes and Binding**, *Application/Class Scope*:

> Every Sinatra application corresponds to a subclass of Sinatra::Base. If you are using the top-level DSL (require 'sinatra'), then this class is Sinatra::Application, otherwise it is the subclass you created explicitly. At class level you have methods like get or before, but you cannot access the request or session objects, *as there is only a single application class for all requests*.

I'm using the top-level DSL.

> Options created via set are methods at class level ... You can reach
>   the scope object (the class) like this: settings from within the
>   request scope

- Bearing in mind what has been said @FrederickCheung in comments and quote from Scopes and Binding, whether this approach would worked if I ever need more than one dyno/worker (currently this app using only one dyno)?

---

### *Summary*

- How should I handle described situation with users and their corresponding threads in Sinatra, how good or bad are approaches from the examples above?

Any comment or reference is welcome.

Comment: This won't work if you ever need more than one worker/dyno

Comment: @FrederickCheung can you clarify? I guess, every dyno/worker has it's own Ruby interpreter with it's own ObjectSpace so the data_thread object may be omitted on the interpreter(dyno/worker) where program requires it with ObjectSpace._id2ref(session[:data_thread])?

Comment: Exactly - an object_id is meaningless in another process

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this design makes sense. Why does each user need its own thread? Why would one request ever join a thread created by another request? Even if it were possible (by using only one dyno), I don't think it is a good way of doing what you want to do.

Based on the description of the app in the question, you want to run some `calculate` method after the `write_collections` method finishes. So, why can't the `write_collections` method call some `calculate` method? Or, why can't an after filter or observer be used to do the calculation?

More generally, you seem to be confounding two separate functions:

1. The `calculate` functionality
2. `GET /calculate`

I think there should only be one trigger for calling the `calculate` functionality. It is either upon completion of `write_collections` **or** when the user requests it (`GET /calculate`).

The more general solution is to have the `calculate` functionality run in the background, and save the results to the database. Later, when the user makes a request, it is ready and can be returned quickly.